# Post with AJAX and PHP - How is this really working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

1.) To post the content (i.e. text) from an ID and then get the variables in PHP in the post.php file?

2.) Call the PHP, like "if ($_POST['Promotion'])". How do you define the _POST in the ajax and in the PHP?

Basically I want the PHP to make a post.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="promo_headline">
<button id="BtnPostPromotion">Post promotion</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#BtnPostPromotion').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'post.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        data: $('#promo_headline').val(),
        success : function(data){                   
            if (data.error === true)
            $('#errorModal').modal("show");
        },
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#errorModal').modal("show");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
});
```

PHP:

```
if ($_POST['Promotion']) {  
    $promo_headline = $_POST['promo_headline'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want `$_POST['Promotion']` available in your PHP, send an object with a key of `Promotion`.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '...',
    type : 'POST',
    data : { Promotion : $('#promo_headline').val() },
    ...
});
```

As another note it kinda makes me sad seeing `jQuery.val()` being used when it is so much more efficient (and just as cross browser friendly) to:

```
document.getElementById('promo_headline').value;
```

Comment: Thanks! But I can't get it to work, seems like the PHP is not responding at all..

Comment: What do you get in the console? You should be able to examine the XHR request/response and see what is being returned

Answer (score 0):

In your jQuery, data needs to be in key value pairs:

```
data: {
    'Promotion' : $('#promo_headline').val()
},
```